# Digital Output as an interrupt Source?

Tags: led, digital-logic, texas-instruments, stellaris

So, I have the `Stellaris Card` from `Texas Instruments`. I am trying to make a `digital output` to be an `interrupt service`. So basically I have a LED on my breadboard that is connected to the card.

**Is there a way that I can use this to use digital output as an interrupt source?**

Comment: Output pin with a LED, being used as an interrupt source makes no sense. Usually the interrupt source would be an input pin, that gets a signal from some source.

Comment: Connect the output to a spare input and use THAT as the source. But it still makes no sense : why not simply call the ISR whenever you set the output?

Comment: an intertupt source to what?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that I can use this to use digital output as an interrupt source?

Not as long as it's configured as output, in any case.

But, on most modern microcontrollers, you can configure any pin to be input or output (but obviously not at the same time).

If the interrupt controller allows that, you can then use that input as an interrupt source.

Whether it does that is said in programming guide / user manual of the microcontroller on that board. You'll need to find that guide, and look for the interrupt controller description. It's probably possible.

Comment: Actually you can often use the input path in parallel to the output.    Easiest thing to do is test it 